# How to make an array with only 1 index to top level?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Business
        )

)
```

But since it only has 1 index element, how can I make it top level removing the zero index?  Because I want to reference this array like so $category->name instead of $category[0]->name

I know I can re-build this with a foreach loop but I was hoping there might be a PHP builtin function that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$category = $category[0];
echo $category->name;
```

Instead of the first line, you could also do

```
$category = reset($category);
```

[`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) will reset the array pointer to the first element and return that element. So this will also work with an associative array (which might have elements but not one with the index `0`).

Comment: @Rick No need to feel dumb. Nobody was born knowing everything :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [current](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```
$category = current($category);
echo $category->name;
```

or

```
echo current($category)->name;
```

Using `current` solves the problem of the index not actually being `0`. Another advantage to `current` is that it **doesn't affect the array's internal pointer in any way**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = $category[0];
```